# Longtable margin

Tags: margins, longtable

I use the package **longtable** for build tables. But the table has many columns, then it to fall outside the limits page.
How do I fix this? And how to change the margin for tables?

Look at the example:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: use package `ltablex` or `ltxtable`. Documentations are available by running `texdoc <package name>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *need* the table to be a bit wider than the normal text width and have it leak into the margins slightly you can set the left margin to be negative, for example

```
\setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
```

alternatives are to use a smaller font, for example putting `\small` before the `longtable`. Also you have not shown your TeX code but it looks like you have used `c` columns. As in a standard `tabular` `c` columns never wrap over a line automatically, so you may want to make some of your columns fixed width with `p{3cm}` or whatever width is suitable, then TeX will linebreak and justify the entries to that width.